# Uploading ftp: file reverts to old one?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

What does it mean when you upload a file to your ftp server using sftp and the server automatically reverts the file to an older version?

I was wondering what was going on. The file I am transferring is verified as the one I want. I've tried deleting the old file, and overwriting it.

What I see using fileZilla is the new file, 208 bytes, uploaded successfully, but then half a second later it reverts back to the old version, about 201 bytes.

What is going on here?

Comment: I also have this problem over plain FTP, also Filezilla client on Windows. possible FileZilla forum reference: http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files don't automagically overwrite themselves, make sure you don't have a script or a running process that writes to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some strange (failing) storage solution on the server?